# iOS: Local Interactive notification does not seem to run didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

**I am trying to make my app's local interactive notifications work even in the case that the app has been killed and is not running,** even in background mode I put the following code into my app at the end of `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:defaultsName];
if (launchOptions) {
    [userDefaults setObject:launchOptions forKey:@"launchOptions123"];
    [userDefaults synchronize];
} else {
    NSLog(@"here were past launch options %@", [userDefaults objectForKey:@"launchOptions123"]);
}
```

My process is (all on simulator)

(1) launch app
(2) kill app and wait for interactive local notification
(3) select button on interactive local notification
(4) rerun app (press play again within xcode)

**I would expect when I relaunch the app from pressing play on xcode to see something non-null in my log statement `here were past launch options` because the most recent prior run would have launched from an interactive push. However, I don't see anything.**

Note that I am using this work around in the firstplace because when I kill the app, Xcode stops logging and never resumes logging even when the app is relaunched. Similarly, I tried retrieving logs off the device via Xcode, but all I see listed are crash logs from weeks/months ago, without any recent actvitiy.

**My questions are** (1) how can I handle an interactive local push notification when my app is not running at all and (2) why does `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` appear not to be running at all?

Comment: Have you used break points instead of / as well as logging?

Comment: @Wain Break points are not working. As soon as I kill the app on the simulator, Xcode seems to become disconnected from the simulator so that when I reopen the app on the simulator, xcode is not logging events.

Comment: @ThePumpingLama I stand corrected. These are local notifications. I have removed the word 'push' to avoid confusion.

Comment: Maybe this is an Xcode question then, you need to start the app from Xcode but make it wait for external activation rather than start it in the simulator and hope Xcode will see it

Comment: @Wain This is not primarily an xcode question. My primary question is why do I not see anything saved in NSUserDefaults to show evidence that didFinishLaunchingWithOptions actually ran once the user interacted with a local notification.